# Help understanding custom post type and children

Tags: custom-post-types, children

We are considering restructuring our Wordpress site, and I'm trying to better understand how to use custom post types and (possibly) child posts to better organize and control content.

The site has three different article types, so we'll set up three custom post types:

- Research Articles
- News Articles
- Editorials

All of our articles (regardless of type) have unique manuscript IDs, and we currently use that for the post slug:

```
domain.com/<manuscriptID>
```

That works great - what we would like to do, however, is for every article to have the same three child posts like this (each set would have different content relating to its parent article):

```
domain.com/<manuscriptID>/metrics
domain.com/<manuscriptID>/citation
domain.com/<manuscriptID>/media
```

Once creating custom post types and setting the hierarchical flag to "true", is what I have above possible? Would the permalink structure be possible?

Comment: What you want is possible. I have one concern though, creating a hierarchical post type has a huge drawback if you have a large amount (like in a couple of hundred) of posts, it crashes your backend. It is because Wordpress goes through all posts to build a tree which is a very expensive operation which will time out on a large amount of posts.

Comment: If they are always the same and aren't really content on their own but metadata to the article you might consider using a custom endpoint: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint